# pass value from a Webform button click to a MVC Area in a single solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms, parameter-passing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I just need a proper approach and solution to this problem.
I have a Web Application with WebForms and I have recently added a MVC Area to same solution.
What I want is to pass value from WebForms to be accessed in MVC Area.
I have a Button in webforms

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")?id=' + $('#Button1').val()" />
```

On click of Button1 I want to redirect to MVC controller and display the parameter value on MVC View 
MVC Area :- NewSampleMVCArea/Home/Index

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
```

}

`<label>@Html.Action("GetNewParameter", "Home")</label>`
 And the Action method looks like below

```
public ActionResult GetNewParameter(string Year)
    {
        string getId = Year;
        return View(getId);
    }
```

What if I want to display value of Year inside the `<label></label>`

Answer (score 0):

In WebForms tradition, you can handle `click` in a postback event:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("NewSampleMVCArea/Home/Index");
}
```

According to updates, this can be done further more:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var id = Button1.ClientID;
        Response.Redirect("NewSampleMVCArea/Home/Index/" + id);
    }
```

The `HomeController` will have 2 actions:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        ViewBag.Year = id;
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetNewParameter(string Year)
    {
        string getId = Year;
        dynamic model = new ExpandoObject();
        model.getId = getId;
        return PartialView(model);
    }
}
```

and the respective views are:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<label>@Html.Action("GetNewParameter", new { Year = ViewBag.Year })</label>
```

and

```
@Model.getId
```

Comment: Ok great but how do I pass a Parameter value with that

Comment: If you need `Button1` id, there's `Button1.ClientID` for you. Or you can place a hidden field which `runat=server` to access its value upon `Button1_Click`.

Comment: This answer helped me..Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass it via query string, and use the model binder from MVC.

Use `Response.Redirect("NewSampleMVCArea/Home/Index/?val="+ val.ToString());` from your web forms app. Then add parameters to your action:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var val = Button1.val(); // or whatever value you want
    Response.Redirect("NewSampleMVCArea/Home/Index/?val="+ val.ToString());
}

public ActionResult Index(string val)
{ 
    // use val here
    return View(); //returns .cshtml view
}
```

For displaying it in view, use @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.val) where val is a property in your model. Learn some ASP.NET MVC tutorial for more information on how to bind data in view to model/viewmodel.

Comment: thanks for reply, I tried it hits the Index() but what if further I want to display value of  int "year" to a label in MVC .cshtml file. Can you tell how it could be done